# How can I change my CefSharp browser's user agent string and proxy?

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I already know how to set my CefSharp browser's **starting** user agent and proxy. But, I don't know how to **change** my browser's user agent and proxy while the program is running.

How can I change my CefSharp browser's user agent string to the text contents of *UserAgentStringTextBox* whenever I click the *LoadUserAgentStringButton* button?

How can I change my CefSharp browser's proxy to the text contents of *ProxyTextBox* whenever I click the *LoadProxyButton* button?

I've tried the following code, but it didn't visibly do anything:

```
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Proxy
{
    public partial class ProxyForm : Form
    {
        private ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        private CefSettings settings;

        public ProxyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeWebBrowser();
        }

        private void InitializeWebBrowser()
        {
            settings = new CefSettings();

            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "111.47.13.3:80");
            settings.UserAgent = "Hello!";

            Cef.Initialize(settings);

            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(string.Empty) { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

            Controls.Add(browser);
        }

        private void LoadProxyButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Remove("proxy-server");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", ProxyTextBox.Text);
        }

        private void LoadUserAgentStringButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            settings.UserAgent = UserAgentStringTextBox.Text;
        }

        private void LoadWebsiteButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            browser.Load(WebsiteTextBox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

The following 2 pictures show what happens when I load the website "whatsmyuseragent.com" **WITHOUT** attempting to change the default user agent string (Hello!) and proxy (111.47.13.3:80).

[image]
[image]

The following 2 pictures show what happens when I load the website "whatsmyuseragent.com" **WITH** attempting to change the default user agent string (Hello!) and proxy (111.47.13.3:80) -----> to the user agent string "Hey!" and proxy "213.85.92.10:80".

[image]
[image]

Which, as you can see, was unsuccessful.

## **Thank you for taking the time to read my question!**

Comment: The basic assumption that you can change `CefSettings` values after `Cef.Initialize` is called is incorrect. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1308 for background info on setting the proxy settings. There's no easy way to change the `UserAgent` after `Initialize` has been called, You can implement `IRequestHandler.OnBeforeResourceLoad` and change the relevant header. Search the `GitHub` project, should be some examples in previous issues. I don't have time to provide a detailed answer at the moment. if you need more help then might be best to ask on the CefSharp Gitter channel.

Comment: The answer to a similar question can be found here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095566/cefsharp-3-set-proxy-at-runtime/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095566/cefsharp-3-set-proxy-at-runtime/)