# How to use different proxies for each tab/window

Tags: cefsharp

I have been trying to use CefSharp to process html pages for an automation system.

I need to use different proxy for each browser tab/window. How can I do it? Create a new application domain and run multiple instances at the same time in different application domains in case each instance will not interfere with each other?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `CefSharp` does not support multiple `AppDomains`, so you'd have to use a different wrapper if you actually require support for that. You isolate browsers using a `RequestContext` e.g. `browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext`. Register for the `Browser Initialized` event (has a slightly different name in each of the projects, so look at the source. That should be the first place you can set the proxy. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36106994/4583726

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/509ab98b050a0fb3338c55f4d48480506c008d3f/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserTabUserControl.cs#L191

Answer (score 0):

If CefSharp is not a requirement for your task, you can achieve setting a different proxy for each tab with the Chromium-based Ghost Browser: https://ghostbrowser.com/blog/set-different-proxy-for-each-tab/.