# Setting proxy in middle of application via CefSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, chromium, cefsharp

I am trying to add a proxy, I need to do this multiple times during the application. I use the below code to assign the setting at the start.

```
CefSettings cfsettings = new CefSettings();
cfsettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", proxy.Key + ":" + proxy.Value);
cfsettings.UserAgent = "My/Custom/User-Agent-AndStuff";
Cef.Initialize(cfsettings);
```

As you can see I initialize the browser, that works fine for the first ever time, but what if I want to change the proxy in the middle of the application?

I tried running that code again to sort of try and "reinitiailize" the settings to change the proxy server but I received the following error when trying to do so:

```
System.Exception: 'Cef can only be initialized once. Use Cef.IsInitialized to guard against this exception.'
```

Using WinForms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CefSharp 3 set proxy at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095566/cefsharp-3-set-proxy-at-runtime)

Comment: How is that even relevant? I'm trying to set it in the middle of the application, not runtime.

Comment: Runtime? What does "middle of the application" even mean if it doesn't mean runtime? If you want help, lose the attitude and explain yourself properly so it avoids ambiguity.