# CefSharp WPF proxy authentification

Tags: c#, browser, proxy, chromium, cefsharp

I am trying to install a proxy with authentication on the chromiumWebBrowser instance, but all the options that I could find on the Internet do not fully suit me. For example

```cs
CefSharpSettings.Proxy = new ProxyOptions(
    ip:       proxy.Split (":") [0],
    port:     proxy.Split (":") [1],
    username: proxy.Split (":") [2],
    password: proxy.Split (":") [3]);
```

works great for me, but I also need to change the proxy while using the browser, which is not possible in this way. I assume that the `GetAuthCredentials` method is what I need, but I also could not find its correct use.

Comment: It depends on the operating system and version of VS and it TLS/SSL is beiong used .  VS is set to use the default  version of TLS of windows.  So if you have latest windows then you are probably set to TLS 1.2 (since windows doesn't support TLS 1.3 at the moment).  Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 due to security issues. June this year Microsoft pushed a security update that disabled TLS 1.0/1,1 on servers (not clients).  So client in code have 1.0/1.1 will still use 1.0/1.1.  Otherwise will use default.  You can change registry to change options.

Comment: Ok, how should i do this?
(windows 10 pro 1909, vs 2019)

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-network-related-errors-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: It seems to me that this does not fit, because "but I also need to change the proxy while using the browser"

Comment: If you are using a browser you need to set the http header properly (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1).  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the working and non working code.  Look at headers in first request to see the actual settings.  You may need to add a User Agent header which specifies the browse type being used.

Comment: Please make sure you've read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#proxy-resolution

Comment: Yes, i readed it, but this documentation have no offical examples, only [link on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095566/cefsharp-3-set-proxy-at-runtime) but it have only winforms example, and because i asking here

Comment: The example provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37461387/4583726 should work the same in `WPF` as it does in `WinForms`. You'll need to implement http://cefsharp.github.io/api/84.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestHandler_GetAuthCredentials.htm to handle the request for username/password.

Comment: If you followed the links provided in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#proxy-resolution you would have read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation (which has a proxy example).

Comment: This example have no auth. I guess `IRequestHandlerGetAuthCredentials` can help me with this, but i didn't see anyone normal implementation. I don't know how to do this, because in c# you need to realize all methods from interface, and if you'll help me with this, or provide link with good implenetation, I would be very grateful.